# Trying to center the input box inside a div

Tags: html, css, centering

http://jsfiddle.net/6dme5y8u/5/

I need center the input in div.
The input always float right.
Is there any way to do it?
I tried many time any can't find any solve.
add anything is ok.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}

#siteInfo {     
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

input {
    padding: 5%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid violet;
}

html css centering
```

```html
<div id="siteInfo">
   <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
        <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
        <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
        <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
</div>
```

Comment: Without any change in the styles of `#siteInfo`?

Comment: change the #siteInfo is ok but It looks can't be different

Comment: avoid percentage value with padding, use pixel value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by changing the style of `#siteInfo` like this:

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}

#siteInfo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

input {
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid violet;
}

html css centering
```

```html
<div id="siteInfo">
   <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
        <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
        <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
        <span>132321</span><br />
   <input value="Test" \>
</div>
```

Comment: see angin please,I was change something of code.

Comment: where would you like to put `<span>132321</span>` ? left? what is your expected output?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6dme5y8u/15/

Comment: I want center them.

Comment: I editet my answer

Comment: let me see and test.

Comment: hey do you have discord?
I tried this on my website,and it other input float left.
I can't show this website on it.
so can you give me your discord or any chat way.

Comment: Ok, here is my telegram id: `@sa_shamloo`

Comment: where can I add it.
This is my first time to use telegram.

Comment: Give me your id, and I'll send you a message

Comment: oh I know,see it please.

Answer (score -1):

how about this? setting inputs margin to 5% auto will make it center to its parent div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body{
    background: yellow;
  }

  #siteInfo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 50%;
  }

  input{
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 5%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid violet;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="siteInfo">
    <input value="Test" \>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see angin please,I was change something of code.